# Access children in parent component using ng-content

Tags: templates, angular, parent-child

I have parent component which has dynamic number of children within its template.

This is how parent is created:

```
<parent>
    <child>
        custom html
    </child>
    <child>
        custom html
    </child>
</parent>
```

This is parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <div class="parent-children">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>        
    `
})
```

My problem is that I want to dynamically insert specific HTML between child 1 and child 2 and best option would be to do it inside parent component.

Basically I need something like this (although this isn't working, just demonstration):

```
@Component({
        selector: 'parent',
        template: `
            <div class="parent-children">
                <ng-content select="[children][0]></ng-content>
                <div> custom html</div>
                <ng-content select="[children][1]></ng-content>
            </div>        
        `
    })
```

Please note that I have access to children in parent but that doesn't help much:

```
@ContentChildren(Child) 
private children: QueryList<Child>;
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar to this? Basically to select specific childrens in parent template although they are already defined in base html tag of parent (not dinamically added from some dataSource via ngFor).

Regards